# MySQL: INSERT IGNORE or ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with checking multiple and not unique columns

Tags: mysql

i want to insert rows IF a row containing the specific values exists, and if not update it.

Concretely:

A column `user_id=5, user_zip=12345, distance=600` exists on the database.

If i try to insert `user_id=5, user_zip=12345, distance=700` it should just update the `distance`

but i try to insert `user_id=5, user_zip=67890, distance=800` it should insert a new row.

I can't define the columns `user_zip` and `distance` unique, so that i can use the on duplicate key update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` works. With a unique constraint on `(user_id, user_zip)`, this should work:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (user_id, user_zip, distance) VALUES (5,12345,600)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE distance=600;
```

You don't have to define user_zip unique (that's how I understand your question), just the combination of `user_id` and `user_zip`. So you still can have 2 or more rows with the same `user_id`, just the `user_zip` can't match on those rows.