# Checking for duplicate of two columns with MySQL on Insert, but neither are unique

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

This question here:

[MySQL: INSERT IGNORE or ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with checking multiple and not unique columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025651/mysql-insert-ignore-or-on-duplicate-key-update-with-checking-multiple-and-not-u)

Is similar, but not quite.

I am trying to build a watch list, using a table as follows:

```
    recordId    |    itemId   |   userId    |    dateAdded
```

The recordId is the only `unique` column and ss an autoincrement ID field.

itemId, userId and dateAdded can be duplicated individually, but not altogether.

So, if a user has already added an item to his/her watch list, I want it to just update the dateAdded.

Rows therefore may contain the same userId many times (as the user may wish to 'watch' multiple items) and it may include the itemId many times (as the same item may be 'watched' by many users) but a combination of both the userId and itemId matching a record which already exists should cause an update.

Is there a single statement way to do this, or do I need to ask the database if `userId = & postingUser & and itemId = & requestedId &` before attempting an insert?

Comment: What is the type of column `dateAdded`?

Comment: `dateAdded` is a unix Integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do this:

```
insert into <tablename> (itemId, userId)
values (?, ?)
on duplicate key update dateAdded = now();
```

*where the ?'s stand for the new values you're inserting*

This is assuming you have defined a unique index for `(itemId, userId)`:

```
CREATE TABLE <table> (
  `recordId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `itemId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateAdded` timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (`recordId`),
  UNIQUE KEY itemuser (`itemId`,`userId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

How this works:

- when you try to insert a row, MySQL will check for key conflicts
- since you've created a unique key for the combination of `(itemId, userId)`, this will be checked
- if there is no conflict, MySQL will go ahead and insert the row
- if there is a conflict, MySQL will fall back to the `on duplicate key` clause, which updates the `dateAdded` column's value

Comment: Thanks, having pondered over this for a while I think I've changed my plan slightly, to delete rather than update the record, do I just change the `update` to delete? I'm guessing so, but my next question is, how would I get an output from this to notify the user? ie, the new function would be that when a user clicks "add to watchlist" it adds the item, but if it's already added it acts as a remove button.